# Using rsync in bash script with variables

Tags: bash, variables, rsync

I want to use `rsync` cmd in a bash script to sync files in a `src` and `dst`. I developed a simple bash script to do it as you can see in following

```
#!/bin/bash
   
src= "/path/to/source"
dst= "/path/to/dist"
   
find ${src[@]} -type f -not -path "*/build/*" -not -path "*/.git/*" -printf %P\\0 | \
rsync -r --prog    ress --files-from=- --from0 "${src[@]}" "${dst[@]}"
```

when I run the bash file, I got the error `rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1801) [Receiver=v3.2.3]`. The problem stems from using `src` and `dst` as variables in `rsync`. When I changed it to something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
   
src= "/path/to/source"
dst= "/path/to/dist"

find ${src[@]} -type f -not -path "*/build/*" -not -path "*/.git/*" -printf %P\\0 | \
 rsync -r --prog    ress --files-from=- --from0 /path/to/source /path/to/dist
```

the bash file works fine.

Comment: Check your script with https://shellcheck.net

Comment: Neither of your variables are arrays. You can't have spaces after the `=` (or before it) in an assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Why not doing exclusion with `rsync`?

```sh
#!/bin/env bash
   
src="/path/to/source"
dst="/path/to/dist"

rsync --recursive --progress --exclude={'*/build/*','*/.git/*'} "$src" "$dst"
```